# Regex: Convert HTML into JSON format

Tags: javascript, html, json, regex

How can I create the following object:

```
{
   element: "div",
   class: ["OneClass", "TwoClass"],
   text: "This is some text"
}
```

from the following HTML:

`<div class="OneClass TwoClass">This is some text</div>`

Comment: For starters, make an effort of your own, and then come back with it, if you can't make it work...we are not here to write it up for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div');
var obj = {};
var clsList = el.classList.value.split(' ')
obj.element = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
obj.class = clsList;
obj.text = el.textContent
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<div class="OneClass TwoClass">This is some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
var html = '<div class="OneClass TwoClass">This is some text</div>';
var el = $(html);
var obj = {
  class: el.attr("class").split(/ /),
  text: el.text(),
  element: el.prop("tagName")
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Output:

```
{"class":["OneClass","TwoClass"],"text":"This is some text","element":"DIV"}
```